# Include Zend In Symfony 2

Tags: zend-framework, symfony

I have a problem for including Zend Framework in Symfony 2 IN PRODUCTION, because when i use it on local there is no problem ...

I just commited my work on my production server and i have this error :

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Gdata_AuthSub' not found

And there is this error for any classes of Zend Framework ...
This is my autoload which is good for localhost :

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
    $loader->add('Zend_', __DIR__.'/../vendor/zf/library');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/../vendor/zf/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
return $loader;
?>
```

There is probably a problem with the include path but i don't know why ...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: did you install Zend with Composer? And I don't think it is a good idea to include the complete Zend Framework in Symfony, you should only include those modules of ZF which you want to use.

Comment: I have a composer.json file in vendor/zf/, is it ? And how can i choose ? I just have to delete in library what i don't want ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Composer to pull in the components you need from ZF2 then you could use the information at [Zend Framework site Composer info page](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer)

As an example you can add code like this to your composer.json file to enable the repository:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],


"require": {
"zendframework/zend-config": "2.0.*",
"zendframework/zend-http": "2.0.*"
},
```

You place the names of the packages you want to pull in under the "require" section and the list of available packages is at the link I supplied so you can check the names there.
When you go to install the dependencies you can use this command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Does that help? :-)

Comment: Just had another look and I can see you are trying to use ZF1 with Symfony 2 rather than ZF2....my answer was based on ZF2 so apologies for confusing matters :-)